# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path') at E:\routes\web\post.js:67:27

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, blogs

I am building a blog web app to post and edit using Node.js. It seems to work when I update an image and text together, but when I try to edit my content, the page says "This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" And my VS code terminal shows
"

E:\routes\web\post.js:67
post.image = req.file.path

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
at E:\routes\web\post.js:67:27
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"

Below is my post.js file

```
var express = require("express")
var multer = require("multer")
var crypto = require("crypto")
var path = require("path")

var ensureAuthenticated = require("../../auth/auth").ensureAuthenticated

var Post = require("../../models/post")

var router = express.Router()

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads/images/',
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function(err, raw){
            cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
        })
    }
})

var upload = multer({storage:storage})

router.use(ensureAuthenticated)

router.get("/", function(req, res){
    Post.find({userID: req.user._id}).exec(function(err,posts){
        if(err){console.log(err)}

        res.render("post/posts", {posts:posts})
    })
})

router.get("/add", function(req, res){
    res.render("post/addpost")
})

router.post("/add", function(req, res){
    var newPost = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content,
        userID: req.user._id
    })

    newPost.save(function(err, post){
        if(err){console.log(err)}
        res.redirect("/posts")
    })
})

router.get("/:postId", function(req, res){
    Post.findById(req.params.postId).exec(function(err, post){
        res.render("post/viewpost", {post: post})
    })
})

router.get("/edit/:postId", function(req, res){
    Post.findById(req.params.postId).exec(function(err, post){
        res.render("post/editpost", {post: post})
    })
})

router.post("/update", upload.single('image'), async function(req, res){
    const post = await Post.findById(req.body.postid)

    post.title = req.body.title
    post.content = req.body.content
    post.image = req.file.path

    // post.save()

    try{
        let savePost = await post.save()
        console.log("savepost", savePost)
        res.redirect("/posts/" + req.body.postid)

    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error happened")
        res.status(500).send(err)
    }

})


module.exports = router
```

And this is editpost.ejs file

```
<%- include('../_partial/_header'); -%>
 
 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Edit Post: <%= post.title %></h1>
    </div>
</div>
 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form action="/posts/update" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
 
                <label for="inputTitle">Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" id="inputTitle" name="title"
                    value="<%= post.title %>"
                />
            </div>
 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputContent">Content</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="inputContent" placeholder="Content" name="content"><%= post.content %></textarea>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" id="postid" name="postid" value="<%= post._id %>">
 
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="image">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Update</button>
            </div>
    </div>
 
    </form>
</div>
 
 
 
 
<%- include ('../_partial/_footer'); -%>
```

I tried to fix this for hours, but I have no idea what's wrong. What should I do to fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: As the error tells you, in the line with `post.image = req.file.path`, you are attempting to read the property `path` of `undefined`. That means that `req.file` must be `undefined`, because then you'd do `undefined.path` there. This means that no file (image) was passed in the request. So, you either need to ensure that there is always an image sent or you add a check for whether `req.file` is even set before you attempt to access it.

Comment: @CherryDT First, thanks for your comment. But I am not sure what I can do here if I want to upload text content whether I upload an image or not. Can you tell me what "add a check" means? or what to do?

Comment: @skforiss By 'add a check', he means you have to create a middleware that checks if ```req.file``` exists and return an error or a redirect or whatever if what is required is not there.